# Animate sprite with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, sprite

Does anybody know the best approach to animating a sprite using jquery. There are 3 stages of an image that i need to gradually to morph on mouseover and eventually landing on the final one until mouse off.

Here is the image:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: would you also consider «variations on theme»?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: It´s not clear how you´d like it but I put together a demo. See if it fits you needs; http://jsfiddle.net/LeusR/

Comment: @ChrisTill if you're interested in a css3 only effect take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something using CSS3 **transition** and **animation** (it only works on modern browser, see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d))

you can see my example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/hfs22/
 
Main benefits:

- No javascript required, it's 100% pure CSS;
- No need to load images;
- Smooth animation.

HTML is simply `<div><span></span></div>​`: I tried to avoid the inner span in favour of pseudoelements: on Chrome, unfortunately, transitions don't properly work when applied to such elements (see bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54699)

the CSS

```
div {
   height: 100px;
   width : 100px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
   -msie-border-radius: 100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 100px;
   border-radius: 100px;

   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;

   border  : 20px red solid;    
   cursor  : pointer;

}

div span {

   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -msie-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);

   display  : block;
   margin     : 10px 0 0 -20px;
   background : #fff;
   width    : 102px;
   height   : 40px;

   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
   -msie-transition: all 2s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
   -o-transition: all 2s ease;
   transition: all 2s ease;


}

div:hover {
   -webkit-animation : rotation 2s ease;
   -msie-animation : rotation 2s ease;
   -moz-animation : rotation 2s ease;
   -o-animation : rotation 2s ease;
   animation : rotation 2s ease;
}

div:hover span {
   height : 0;
   margin-top : 30px;
}

@-moz-keyframes rotation   {
     0%     { -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%   { -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation   {
     0%     { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}

@-msie-keyframes rotation   {
     0%     { -msie-transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%   { -msie-transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes rotation   {
     0%     { -o-transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%   { -o-transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}


@keyframes rotation   {
     0%     { transform: rotate(45deg); }
     100%   { transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JackalopeZero. I hope Chrome will soon support animation on psuedoelements

Comment: This is fantastic. My only problem is that i am using an image as a background and so I can't have a white block rotating. Is there a way arround this?

Answer (score 0):

here's quick sketch

http://jsfiddle.net/VEuyH/1/

you just need to adjust the image to the animation, i set background to switch -151px every frame, you can also adjust the delay time,
enjoy ;)

Comment: Thats great! How do i go about keeping on the final frame until the mouse moves away? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to adjust that if() in moveBackground function, right now it's set if the sprite reaches maximum of it's length then start over form 0, and continue the rotation. you need to set that if(position>=<image length>){return;} this will stop the spinner

Answer (score 0):

This will look much nicer than your chosen answer:

[See my example](http://jsfiddle.net/VEuyH/12/)

Underneath is an identical static image. If you can make the white parts of this image transparent in photoshop or something this will have a really nice smooth closing effect.