# jQuery sprite animation toggle without plugin

Tags: jquery, animation, sprite

[image: Categorised list]

this here I'm currently using an ascii character for category toggling. But I want to make it into a sprite, like this one:

[image: glyph]

the problem is, I can't find a simple solution without downloading an external plugin, and also I can't figure out how to detect which state the glyph in (the first or the last slide), because on first click I want it to go from first to last slide, and on second click, when closing category- from last to first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

JS:

```
var timer;
var position=0;
var delay = 100;
var block = document.getElementById('image');

var moveBackground = function(){
    position = position - 20;
    if(position>100){
       position=0; 
    }
    block.style.backgroundPosition = position+"px 0px";
    mouseOver();
};

var mouseOver = function(){
   timer = setTimeout(moveBackground,delay);
};

var mouseOut = function(){
   clearTimeout(timer);
}

block.onmouseover= mouseOver;
block.onmouseout= mouseOut ;
```

CSS:

```
 .test {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUWnE.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  }
```

I copied the solution from [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532515/animate-sprite-with-jquery)

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/VEuyH/64/)